# Create a mailing distribution group by outlook office365 API REST

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi, mailing-list

I have been struggling myself last two weeks trying to create a mailing distribution group implementing Office365 API REST, the thing is that I am developing an integration to a interactive agent and I am working over the platform of a company, I am not allowed to make some coding. So, basically I need to figure it out with my account of Office 365 and potential APIs REST requests (endpoints, parameters, etc). 
 
 
I have found interesting endpoints  (just required to be logged on) as: 
 
account personal info:

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me

account received messages: https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages

account contacts:
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts 
 
And I have already created an application at: apps.dev.microsoft.com trying to obtain azure credentials and tokens for OAuth in case I need them to access outlook info 
 
I don't really know if I need to be logged on with tokens besides, my outlook log-in and furthermore no idea on how create a mailing distribution list. 
 
 
Thank's in advance for all the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribution groups are not recommended any more.

You could use [Office 365 groups](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/groups-overview#office-365-groups).  The office 365 Group will works as a conventional Distribution List.  Email will received by all the Group members which send to this email address.

As of today the only way to manage the “ Distribution Lists ” is to use Office 365 Groups.

Reference from:

[Managing Distribution Groups via REST API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/09bf5f1d-f72c-4c08-b95f-44c7f2fdcbff/managing-distribution-groups-via-rest-api?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

Comment: Okay, thank you Alina for the support. I have already tried the MS Graph solution regarding groups but I am still struggling with the access and authentication to the API. I tried the API REST Graph, which requires tokens for authentication, tokens are obtained by creating and app at Azure AD (I did it and kept client_id,password,redirect_uri), right after I did some authorizations API REST calls to get the app token but I couldn't get it, neither set permissions to user to perform the POST requests as API queries of mailing-distribution-groupcreation. What would you suggest?