# Outlook oAuth - retrieve contact lists

Tags: rest, outlook, oauth-2.0

I'm using the Outlook REST API 2.0. The API works good and I can retrieve the contact data.
But you also have an option within outlook to make "contact lists". Now I would like to retrieve these lists, but cannot find it in the API. Is it just not possible or am I seeing it wrong? Weird to not include this data in the API calls.

Thanks in advance,
DrunkenMoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to "distribution lists". The question has been possibly answered here...

[Create a mailing distribution group by outlook office365 API REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160950/create-a-mailing-distribution-group-by-outlook-office365-api-rest)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using the normal Oauth2.0 rest api. But maybe we should implement Microsoft graph as well. Thx!